# Show that $f = 0$ almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

$f$ be an integrable function (not necessarily positive) on [0,1]. Assume that for any $g$ measurable bounded function $g:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we have $$\int_{[0,1]} g(t)f(t)dt = 0$$ Prove $f=0$ a.e

---

I understand that $|g| \leq M$ for some $M>0$ and that the measure of the integration is finite but I have a hard time dealing with $f$ being non-negative here.

Answer (score 2):

Take $g = 1_{\{f \geq 0\}}$ and $g = 1_{\{f < 0\}}$ (show that they are measurable and bounded).

Using these two functions, you get two integrals of the form $\int_A f(t) dt=0$. In both integrals, you know the sign of $f$, which solves your problem.

Comment: Good answer.  I think proving the contrapositive streamlines the argument even further. Suppose $f = 0$ a.e. is not true, then one of $\{f >0 \}$ or $\{ f < 0 \}$ has positive measure.  Assume WLOG the former and let $g = 1_{\{f > 0 \}}$.  Then $\int_{[0,1]} g(t)f(t) \,dt > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

We will prove: if $(X,\mu)$ is a measure space, $f$ an integrable function $X \to \mathbb{R}$, and $\forall E \subseteq X$ measurable, $\int_E f d\mu= 0$, then $f =0$ $\mu$-a.e.

Suppose not $f = 0$ $\mu$ a.e. Claim: there exists $n$ s.t. $\{x \in X \mid |f|(x) > 1/n\}$ does not have $\mu$ measure $0$.

Proof (sketch): Suppose each did, write $S = \{x \in X \mid |f|(x) \neq 0\}$ as a countable union of the above sets. Countable union of null sets is null, hence $S$ is $\mu$-null contradicting the assumption that not $f=0$ a.e.

Let $E= \{x \in X \mid |f|(x) > 1/n\}$ for some $n$ s.t. $\mu(E) > 0$. Decompose $f = f_+ - f_-$ where $f_+ =\max(0, f)$, $f_- = \max(0, -f)$. Then $E = |f|^{-1}((1/n,\infty)) = f_+^{-1}((1/n,\infty)) \cup f_-^{-1}((1/n,\infty)).$, so one of the two $f_+^{-1}((1/n,\infty)), f_-^{-1}((1/n,\infty))$ must not be $\mu$-null. Suppose $\mu(f_+^{-1}((1/n,\infty)))>0$. Then $\int_{f_+^{-1}((1/n,\infty))} f d\mu > \int 1/n d\mu = 1/n \mu(f_+^{-1}((1/n,\infty)))> 0$. Otherwise suppose $\mu(f_-^{-1}((1/n,\infty))) >0$. Then $\int_{f_-^{-1}((1/n,\infty))} f < \int_{f_-^{-1}((1/n,\infty))} -1/n = -1/n \mu(f_-^{-1}((1/n,\infty))) < 0$.

In either case we have found a meaurable set s.t. $\int_E f \neq 0$. Hence $\int_E  f = 0 $ for all measurable sets implies $f = 0$ a.e.

Convince yourself my result implies yours.

Comment: I think it is simpler to do it like this: Set $E = 1_{\{f \geq 0\}}$. If $\{f>0\}$ has positive measure, you can find some $\varepsilon>0$ so that $\delta := \mu(\{f\geq\varepsilon\})>0$. In that case, $\int_E f d\mu \geq \delta \varepsilon > 0$. Therefore, $\{f>0\}$ has measure zero. A similar argument applies for $E = 1_{\{f \leq 0\}}$.

Comment: Yeah your right. I started trying to do it with codomain $\mathbb{C}$, but midway switched to codomain $\mathbb{R}$. Clearly the codomain $\mathbb{C}$ case follows easily from the $\mathbb{R}$ case, so really it should be done your way, but didn't feel like editting.